# Is this a valid proof for why this mapping is onto?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I wrote this proof for a homework self study question. It's different than the proof given in the answers, but I'm wondering whether or not it's still correct. Question and theorems are from *Linear algebra and geometry, David M. Bloom*. Note: this text uses right-hand notation for the composition of maps, i.e. $T(S(a))$ is the same as $a(ST)$.

## Question

Prove that the mapping $T_1$ of Theorem 1.3.6(a) is onto.

## Theorem 1.3.6(a)

Let $A,B$ be sets with $A$ nonempty, and let $S$ be a mapping $A \rightarrow B$. Then, $S$ is one-to-one if and only if there exists a mapping $T_1: B \rightarrow A$ such that $ST_1 = I_A$. Note, $I_A$ is the identity mapping on $A$.

## My Answer

Let $a$ be an arbitrary element of $A$. $ST_1 = I_A \implies aST_1 = aI_A \implies aST_1 = a \implies (aS)T_1 = a$. So, every $a \in A$ is the image of something under $T_1$. Thus, $T_1$ is onto.

Comment: This is correct. The notation is very unusual, though.

Comment: Not in my opinion. I would make it much more explicit by setting $b$ equal to some function of $a$ and then show that $ a = T_1(b)$

Comment: @BrianMoehring You and I had very different undergrad professors.

Comment: Warning. The text apparently writes composition of functions in the opposite order from 98% of mathematicians.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is fine.

The only change I'd advise is to not write a sequence of implications but rather  a sequence of equalities, as
$$(aS)T_1 = a(ST_1) = aI_A = a$$